# Error: Invalid target model for scope

Tags: loopbackjs

Hello loopback cracks,

I have the following problem: a model inherits from the built-in user model. When I run the application 'normally', all is well. When trying to do it in a mocha setup, I get the following error:

```
Error: Invalid target model for scope `Customer.prototype.accessTokens`
```

I can see that the Customer class has most accessors up, but for some reason it seems that accessTokens is not among them. I've been baking my noodle over this all morning. Can someone tell me what exactly this error indicates?

Comment: This happens with other relations, too. It's not limited to customer. It must have something to do with the programmatically created data source!

Comment: Are you using built in model AccessToken ?

Comment: After some more experimentation I found that it happens to all 'hasMany' relationships. After switching the data source using Model.attachTo(dataSource), the hasMany accessor methods are missing.

Comment: I found out you have an answer in Github https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/3885, same as I linked in my answer. I deleted my answer, because you found answer that way.

Comment: That is my question as well. But thanks!